# Issues with bash profile

Tags: bash, macintosh

The following is the contents of my `.profile` which I placed in my user home folder on my Mac (Big Sur)?

`export PS1="\[\033[38;5;206m\]\h:\W \u $ \[\033[0m\]"`

When I activate it, it shows in like this:

```
$ source .profile
\[\033[38;5;206m\]\h:\W \u $ \[\033[0m\]
```

Any ideas what's wrong? I can't get it to activate automatically either.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your default shell definitely bash?
Run `ps` and see if it shows you're running bash or some other shell.

Comment: @JohnQ results of `ps` were:  ```44913 ttys000    0:00.20 /bin/bash -l  
60944 ttys001    0:00.08 -zsh```

Comment: Trying renaming .profile to .bashrc.  If you run `env` are there any settings that might be affecting character escaping? (your example worked fine on my Mac with bash)

Comment: I'm running pyenv? But have no idea how that would affect it..

Comment: Your `ps` output showed both `bash` and `zsh` running; `bash` on `ttys000` and `zsh` running on `ttys001`.  Which one is you?  Try `echo $SHELL`

Comment: Ha! I didn't notice that in the wrapping, @Andy Dalton   @cdp, if you run `tty` it will tell you if you're in ttys000 (bash) or ttys001 (zsh)      `env` from the commandline will just show the variables that are already set in your shell environment.  If this is in your bash window, check your other dot files and see if there's some other .*rc file or something.

Comment: `echo $0` will tell you what shell is running.

Comment: Okay, looks like my normal terminal is running `zsh` but my python virtual env runs `bash` aha so I need two profiles?